# Wrap n-th or less element, wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have drop down menu in wordpress and I have small problem with wrap nth(every 4th element) li.

My code

```
<li id="item1"> ... </li>
<li id="item2"> ... </li>
<li id="item3">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li> Test1</li>
        <li> Test2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="item4">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li> Test3</li>
        <li> Test4</li>
        <li> Test5</li>
        <li> Test6</li>
        <li> Test7</li>
        <li> Test8</li>
        <li> Test9</li>
        <li> Test10</li>
        <li> Test11</li>
        <li> Test12</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery code

```
var divs = $("ul.sub-menu > li");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=4) {
divs.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<div class='column'></div>");
}
```

My results (wrong)

```
   <li id="item1"> ... </li>
   <li id="item2"> ... </li>
   <li id="item3">
       <ul class="sub-menu">
           <div class="column">
               <li> Test1</li>
               <li> Test2</li>
               <li> Test3</li>
               <li> Test4</li>
           </div>   
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="item4">
       <ul class="sub-menu">
           <div class="column">
               <li> Test5</li>
               <li> Test6</li>
               <li> Test7</li>
               <li> Test8</li>
           </div>   
           <div class="column">
               <li> Test9</li>
               <li> Test10</li>
               <li> Test11</li>
               <li> Test12</li>
           </div>   

       </ul>
   </li>
```

What I try achieve:

```
   <li id="item1"> ... </li>
   <li id="item2"> ... </li>
   <li id="item3">
       <ul class="sub-menu">
           <div class="column">
               <li> Test1</li>
               <li> Test2</li>
           </div>   
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="item4">
       <ul class="sub-menu">
           <div class="column">
               <li> Test3</li>
               <li> Test4</li>
               <li> Test5</li>
               <li> Test6</li>
           </div>   
           <div class="column">
               <li> Test7</li>
               <li> Test8</li>
               <li> Test9</li>
               <li> Test10</li>
           </div>
           <div class="column">
               <li> Test11</li>
               <li> Test12</li>
           </div>   

       </ul>
   </li>
```

any idea what I do wrong? It's necessary because "item3" and "item4" are diffrents category and with my code li elements are mix if in first ul is less then 4 items

Answer (score 4):

Wow, what you just did, I didn't know it was possible. :)
Anyway:

```
$('.sub-menu').each(function() {
    var children = $(this).find('> li');
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i+=4) {
        children.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll("<div class='column'></div>");
    }
});
```

This will use the functionality you tried, but it will loop through every submenu independently and the items will be properly grouped.

http://jsfiddle.net/9NUwJ/